# How to use sqlmap payload in browser manually?

Tags: mysql, browser, sql-injection, sqlmap

When we use [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/), it does everything automatically for finding `sql injection` of a website. I'm interested in that I send malicious queries directly in my browser and get the results in it, but when I couldn't find anything, I use `sqlmap` for finding malicious queries. I use the payload that `sqlmap` gives me and enter it in the vulnerable field of the website in my browser. I want to get all databases of the website in my browser, but I cannot get them. Although `sqlmap` uses the payload and gives me all databases of the website. Now my question is how to use `sqlmap` payload in browser manually?

Comment: Hello @ThisIsMe, I am having the same doubt. Did you fnd out how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @MyName Someone posted an answer, you can use mitmproxy instead of burpsuite if you want to use open source tools.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the problem，I have a simple way to sound.

1.you must have burpsuite tools
2.Monitor local 8080 or any port you specify by burpsuite.
3. use the --proxy parameter U of sqlmap. It looks like this.
sqlmap.py -u "URL" --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080
4.you can get all http requests,then you can test it in your browers

good luck to you!

Comment: For people who want to use open source tools, you can use mitmproxy instead of burpsuite.